# VBA to download excel attachment from email, edit it, and send it/run macro on attachment in outlook?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a report with the following format:

r1 Col1   Clmn2   Col3   Col4
r2 itm1   name1  itm1   itm1
r3 itm2   name2  itm2   itm2
r4 itm3   name3  itm3   itm3
r5 itm4   name1  itm4   itm4

I would like to do two things with it.

### Part 1

The report gets sent to multiple people (they will have a script running in outlook as an event handler). The script will do the following:

1. It will listen for the email with a specific subject line and attachment count (i.e. Subject: "Report"; Attachment Count: 1).
2. When the email with the report is received, it will process the email by saving the attachment, reformatting it, and copying and pasting the rows that pertain to that person into the email.

Here is an situational example:

I (name1) receive the email with the report attached. My script automatically processes the email so that when I open it I see an email with an attachment that has only rows 1, 2, and 5 (formatted properly). The email will also have the table (with only rows 1,2, and 5) in the actual body of the email.

Here is the script I have for this so far:

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items
Private Sub Application_Startup()
Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim X As Integer

Set objNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Items = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
end Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Set objNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")

If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
  Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
  Set Msg = Item

 If (Msg.Subject = "Report") And _
 (Msg.Attachments.Count = 1) Then

    ' open wkbk and run import macro
    Dim olDestFldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
    Dim XLApp As Object ' Excel.Application
    Dim XlWK As Object ' Excel.Workbook
    Dim Att As String

    Const attPath As String = "C:\Users\username\Documents\Reports"

    ' New Excel.Application
    Set XLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    ' save attachment
    Set myAttachments = Item.Attachments
    Att = myAttachments.Item(1).DisplayName
    myAttachments.Item(1).SaveAsFile attPath & Att

    ' open personal.xls where macro is stored,
    ' just in case it doesn't open on its own
    On Error Resume Next
    XLApp.Workbooks.Open _
 ("C:\Documents and Settings\username\Application Data\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\PERSONAL.XLS")
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' open workbook and run macro
    XLApp.Workbooks.Open (attPath & Att)

    XLApp.Run ("PERSONAL.XLS!MacroName")
    XLApp.Workbooks.Close
    Kill attPath & Att
    XLApp.Quit
  End If
End If
End Sub
```

As of now, it does not copy the table into the email (idk how to do that). It also doesn't seem to be running the macro. Whenever I open up the attachment, it opens PERSONAL.XLS and the attachment (unformatted).

Is it possible for me to just edit the attachment straight from the outlook script? Like put the excel macro into the excel script instead of trying to run it in the excel application?

### Part 2

The report gets sent to one person:

1. The email with a specific subject line and with an excel attachment (report) will arrive.
2. I will use an outlook rule to move this message to a certain folder and run my script on it.
3. The script will download the excel sheet attachment to a specific path under a standard name with the date (i.e. "Daily Report - MM/DD/YYYY").
4. Then the excel sheet will have to be edited and certain rows of the sheet will be sent to certain emails. I am not sure if the script in steps 1-3 would have to do the editing or if I would call another macro.

**I have written the macro to edit/format the excel sheet, but I do not know how to send it out. There will be a column in the report with full names. I would like to send the modified personal report to those people somehow. It will be kind of like pasting their name from the cell to the "To:" field in outlook and then pressing ctrl+k.

Here is an example if I did not explain it well:

r1 Col1   Clmn2   Col3   Col4
r2 itm1   name1  itm1   itm1
r3 itm2   name2  itm2   itm2
r4 itm3   name3  itm3   itm3
r5 itm4   name1  itm4   itm4

I would like to send row 1 ,row 2, and row 5 to name 1; row 1 and row 3 to name 2; row 1 and row 4 to name 3.

**The table can be sent as an attachment, but I also want to paste the table into the email that gets sent.

Thank you ahead of time!!

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible for me to just edit the attachment straight from the outlook script?

No, it is not. The Outlook object model doesn't provide any property or method for that. Extended MAPI (a low level API on which Outlook and other third-party components are based) allows to get an array of bytes which represents an attachment. So, the proper way is to save the attached file and then re-open it for editing or reading the content.

The Outlook object models provides three ways for modifying the body:

1. Body - a plain text.
2. HTML - an HTML markup.
3. A Word editor. The Inspector class provides the WordEditor property which returns an instance of the Document class. So, you can use the Word object model for modifying the body. See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012.aspx).

Finally, you may find the following articles helpful:

1. [How To: Create and send an Outlook message programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/02/outlook-create-send-message/)
2. [How To: Fill TO,CC and BCC fields in Outlook programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/08/outlook-fill-recipients-programmatically/)
3. List item
4. List item